# Why isn't Spring Security Java Config AntMatcher blocking this url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using Spring Boot and Spring Security I configure a super simple application and add security based on URLs but it isn't respected. For example, if I log in as a 'scout' and hit an admin URL like `/api/leaders`, I can still see it.

I've tried many permutations of the URLs, even trying `anyRequest().denyAll()` and the `scout` user can still access it.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.ssoward.scouts"})
public class MainConfiguration {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MainConfiguration.class, args);
    }

    //security
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    static class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return authenticationManager();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api/leaders*").hasRole("ADMIN") //url level security
                    .antMatchers("/api/scouts*").hasRole("USER");   //url level security
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("leader").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN").and()
                    .withUser("scout").password("password").roles("USER");
        }
    }
}
```

The entire project is on Github: https://github.com/ssoward/scouts

Comment: Do you have spring security `DelegatingFilterProxy` mapped over your `/api` URLs ?

Comment: No I don't have that filter. I thought the Spring Boot Actuator would have auto configured it.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Actuator auto configures Spring Security, however when I added the configuration noted above it added it didn't remove the config that Spring Actuator had added.

The solution: disable the Spring Actuator added security by adding the following to your application property file: `security.basic.enabled=false`

Comment: This solution is no longer needed after Spring Boot Milestone 7